# converter software for fortran 77 to fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

i have coding for fortran 77 but i want to converted to fortran 90..where can i donwload the converter software??

Comment: What are you going to do with it once converted?  Code converters typically produce code that works but is hard to work with.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a python solution that I helped write: https://github.com/arktools/fortran_tools

It successfully converted the entire airforce f77 datcom code to f90, so it is well tested. I will be adding some more features as I have time.

If anyone finds it useful/ and makes modifications, feel free to contribute to the project.

Answer (score 7):

The first hit on a Google query for "fortran 77 convert 90" returned [this page](http://www.personal.psu.edu/hdk/fortran.html), which has 3 free tools and 2 commercial ones listed (after clicking the link for "Subprograms, Converters, Key Works").  I've not used Fortran in quite a while, and can't vouch for the quality of any of these tools.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [Lemon Lab f2f](http://bitbucket.org/lemonlab/f2f/). I'm a bit biased, since I was the original developer, but my motivation was due to the fact that I didn't think the alternatives worked very well. Give it a try if you like.

Comment: Works well for my simple purposes (which include avoiding using fortran whenever possible).

Comment: Sadly this is a deal link now.

Comment: https://github.com/MRedies/f2f_mirror

Answer (score 3):

The free program convert (http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/Examples/convert.f90) will convert from Fortran 77 fixed-source form to Fortran 90/95/2003 free-source form and make some simple transformations, such as declarations.   There are also some commercial products, such as SPAG (http://www.polyhedron.com/spag0html).

Comment: Thanks! The first URL seems to go directly to http://www.nag.co.uk/. Do you have an updated URL for the program? Or do you have any recommended program convert from Fortran 90 to Fortran 77?

Comment: The two links are broken

Answer (score 3):

I have found and used three programs `convert.f90` (Michael Metcalf), `preconvert.f90` (Purple Sage Computing Solutions, Inc.) and `to_f90.f90` (Alan Miller).

None of them worked 100% like I expected. Results depends on how closely your source matches what the programs expect to see.

For your convenience I have zipped the source files up and hosted them here:
[Source Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?g2q928lyl1xqpjd)

I have used Compaq Visual Fortran 6.5 to compile into three separate projects. If you want the projects also use this link
[CVF 6.5 Projects](http://www.mediafire.com/?3v1vrr28mici41c)

Best of luck.

Comment: I wonder why I got a downvote without a comment?