# How to update Fortran 77 programs to more modern Fortran to improve readability?

Tags: fortran, readability

I am attempting to update the following Fortran 77 program using more modern Fortran languages to improve its readability. Can anyone provide some suggestions? I tried using find and replace to change "IS" to a more readable variables, but that caused type cast problems. This task proved to be very tedious for other Fortran 77 programs much larger than this one.

```
C         3D ISING MODEL
C         Critical temperature TC = 4.5116=1/.22165
          DIMENSION IS(10,10,10), EX(13)
          REAL *8 R(1)
          DATA IS/1000*1/
          ITMAX=5000
          ISTART=4000
          L=10
          NR=1
          ISEED=768521034
          M=L*L*L
          DO 1000 K=1,24
          TR=0.05+(K-1)*.05
          T=TR/.221655
          MR=0.
          DO 3 I=1, 13, 2
3         EX(I)=EXP(-2*(I-7.)/T)
          DO 2 ITIME=1,ITMAX
          DO 1 K1=1,L
          K1P1=K1+1
          K1M1=K1-1
          IF(K1.EQ.1) K1M1=L
          IF(K1.EQ.L) K1P1=1
          DO 1 K2=1,L
          K2P1=K2+1
          K2M1=K2-1
          IF(K2.EQ.1) K2M1=L
          IF(K2.EQ.L) K2P1=1
          DO 1 K3=1,L
          K3P1=K3+1
          K3M1=K3-1
          IF(K3.EQ.1) K3M1=L
          IF(K3.EQ.L) K3P1=1
        IEN=7+IS(K3,K2,K1)*(IS(K3M1,K2,K1)+IS(K3P1,K2,K1)+IS(K3,K2M1,K1)
     &  +IS(K3,K2P1,K1)+IS(K3,K2,K1M1)+IS(K3,K2,K1P1))
          CALL GGUBS(ISEED,NR,R)
          IF(EX(IEN).LT.R(1)) GOTO 1
          IS(K3,K2,K1)=-IS(K3,K2,K1)
          M=M+2*IS(K3,K2,K1)
C          WRITE(*,*) M,ITIME
1         CONTINUE
          IF (ITIME.GT.ISTART) MR=MR+M
2         CONTINUE
          WRITE(*,*) FLOAT(MR)/1000./FLOAT((ITMAX-ISTART)),TR
          WRITE(1,*) FLOAT(MR)/1000./FLOAT((ITMAX-ISTART)),TR
1000      CONTINUE
          STOP
          END

        SUBROUTINE GGUBS(ISEED,NR,R)
        IMPLICIT REAL *8(A-H,O-Z)
        DIMENSION R(NR)
        DATA D2P31M/2147483647.D0/
        DATA D2P31/2147483648.D0/
        DO 7 I=1,NR
        ISEED=MOD(16807.D0*ISEED, D2P31M)
        R(I)=ISEED/D2P31
    7   CONTINUE
        RETURN
        END
```

I am still learning Fortran. I have a very old text book on Fortran applied to Molecular Dynamics with the following Fortran example. I was faced with the difficulty of learning a new language and translating Fortran help from new to ancient Fortran. I have spent time researching the problem and discovered that forcing non-implicit helps me to understand the program better. I am struggling with with some of Fortran's machine-like features like limited line space, character column syntax, and indenting the code to look neater without breaking the logic. In general, making the code look more readable without breaking the logic has been the greatest learning curve for me.

Comment: The previous question is for software to convert FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 90.  This question implies manual conversion.

Comment: You could improve readability just by adding indentation to the code above.  It is written more in a Fortran 66 style than 77 style.

Comment: one thing you need to do is learn about implicit typing. That is the cause of your error changing variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I included additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tools to convert FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 90 ([converter software for fortran 77 to fortran 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305523/converter-software-for-fortran-77-to-fortran-90)).  You might start with one of those.  If the code will be continued to be used unchanged, then regard it as legacy code and don't tinker with it.  If its not broken, don't fix it.    If the code is going to be improved or expanded, porting to Fortran 90 will help the programmer.    Improving from FORTRAN 77 to Fortran >=90 is an investment; balance how much investment to make versus how much programming work you want to do on the code.    Make changes in stages and regression test the program to make sure that you don't introduce bugs.  The work can be non-trivial.  To have fully modern code you should remove the implicit declaration and declare all of the variables.  Then you can rename some variables to have more meaningful names without concern for implicit typing.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you might learn more if you fore go the converter and update your programs manually.  Start with [this](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Modernizing+Old+Fortran).  Other things to consider:

- Use free format
- Convert `DO WHILE` (deprecated) to `DO ... IF( ) EXIT ... END DO`

  **Note** Need opposite logical expressions; for example, the logical operator `<=` becomes `>`
- Consider replacing old intrinsic functions with more specific ones
- Replace old logical operators in `IF( ) THEN` with modern notation
- Modernize variable declarations, making use of `MODULE`, `PARAMETER` for [physical] constants, `USE` for functions and subroutines, double precision (if needed), `INTENT` for dummy variables on functions and subroutines, and--finally--`CHARACTER(LEN= )`
- Text labels on `DO` loops
- `ALLOCATABLE` arrays if appropriate
- Good housekeeping: `CLOSE` statements paired with `OPEN` statements
- Replace common tasks with modern intrinsic functions (e.g. `maxval`)

Finally, do a "thorough" compile using `gfortran -g -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -O2` to isolate and address potential problems.

A more comprehensive list of possible changes can be found [here](http://standard.handcrafted.codes/).

Comment: 1) "Convert DO WHILE (deprecated) to DO ... IF( ) EXIT ... END DO"
`do while` is deprecated?? I don't think so, pretty much every programming language has a while-loop. I'd consider using an infinite loop with conditional exits bad practice in most cases.

2) "Text labels on DO loops"
Disagree again. I'd say use `ènd do`. If it's difficult to match a `do`with an `end do` the code inside the loop is too complex and should probably be refactored into smaller subroutines.

Comment: @Paul While one might agree that `DO WHILE` versus `DO..ENDDO` is a matter of preference, labeled `DO` loops have their own merits. First is to improve readability in case of complex, multiple nested loops. The second is that they provide a convenient way to break out of a specific `DO` loop via `EXIT label`, for example when breaking out of multiple levels of `DO`, but not all of them.

Comment: @Paul `do while` has indeed been deprecated _by some_ (I can think of a famous example).  Often reasoning that: there is another way, and that way is more general.  I agree it has its place, but as a "general rule" it isn't too bad.

Comment: what does depreciated by some mean? id be shocked and rather upset if do while is depreciated in the standards.

Comment: @george Still a first-class citizen in the standard (no such thing as deprecation there); MR&C was my thought.

Comment: @francescalus: I'm not sure where the idea that features that are targeted toward specific usage cases should be abandoned in favor of general features comes from.  Using that logic, why not deprecate all control constructs besides GOTO?

Comment: @supercat I have no views on whether `do while` should be used or not.  I rarely use it, compared with when I use a `do` with no control and an `exit`, but I'm content with others forming own opinions.  I was just stating what at least one famous textbook says on that point.  And that the language standard does not make it obsolescent.

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here already. I want to add three things that haven't been mentioned yet:

- Rename routine and variable names to something longer and more descriptive. If you get an editor with autocomplete (e.g. Photran or a plugin to most decent text editors) you can still type code effectively.
- Refactor long blocks of code into smaller subroutines. Create some automatic tests in advance to verify that you don't change the behaviour.
- Convert to lower case. Some might disagree here though... :-)